# CodeIgniter local development server can open localhost but when i open url its not working

Tags: php, server, localhost, codeigniter-4

i have install codeigniter 4 from composer to my laptop. and i want to run local development server using php spark serve. after i run it, its looks like this :
[local development server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOmHf.png)

i'm so confused why so many port open. but i try to open default port on localhost:8080, but i get it :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Crdk.png)

i have tried all of port from 8080 to 8090 like on first picture, but all of the port same like default port, cant be reached.

can someone help me in this case? because i have change in my .env file to default port on 8080 but it still cant reached.

i have try like change my configuration on my .env but still cant open the port

Comment: Please share your `.env` file's `APP_URL` configuration.  It must match the port where your application is being served.  Secondly,  what does this command return `php -v`? Lastly,  try using [PHP's built-in server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) instead and update your *APP_URL=http://localhost:4532* accordingly. `php -S localhost:4532 -t public`

Comment: i have make my configuration on my .env to default localhost but i have same like before. so i use your last solution to use php bulit-in server. and run the code. and its work. i so thank to you because i need this for my project on my intership. thank a lot.

Comment: Perfect! I'm glad l could be of help. 